# How to setup the oauth module?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I don't know how to setup the outh module right. I found also the question [How do I configure the Services OAuth sub-module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/how-do-i-configure-the-services-oauth-sub-module) but that answer is very old and ends with a "To be continued..." statement.

So far I get out that I need to generate a context (http://example.org/admin/config/services/oauth/contexts) and a oauth connector (http://example.org/admin/structure/oauthconnector). So I think I setted them correctly but I cannot see where the user may access that.

Could you point me to a tutorial or something like that? I'm not able to find the right words to google that myself. Sorry for that!

Comment: You didn't mention whether you were looking to use the module as a consumer or a provider.

Comment: I want to use it as a consumer.

Comment: You probably want oauth + http_client then, not oauthconnector.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial? I'm not sure how to setup that.

Comment: Try this http://drupal.org/node/1517824
In general, the module and the subject are both horribly undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Drupal Services, REST Server and 3-legged OAuth](http://www.covenantdesign.com/blog/drupal-services-rest-server-and-3-legged-oauth) tutorial here. Just be pay intention in this part :

```
$oauth->fetch("$api_url/node/1");
```

This is just for creating the GET request. If you want to create the POST request. It should be something like.

```
 $oauth->fetch("$api_url/user/vote.json",array('nid'=>10),OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add a comment on rekire's turtorial request on http_client oauth2 setup, so i'll just put it here as it also answers the original question.

If you download the [http_client](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client) module you'll find a readme.org file in /http_client/includes/auth/oauth2/ folder explaining some basic settings by examples from within the [wsclient](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient) module.
I'm using both modules successfully now with basic HTTP authentication.
For a new client, just started looking into the oauth2 alternative.

Examples shown are:
- server-side flow (authorization endpoint)
- user-password flow
- client-credentials flow